# Component's different behavior using jQuery 2, than using jQuery 3 or Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

You can see in the **Codepen 3.4.1** that the yellow list item moves left when moving the mouse quickly over the others list elements (as it also occurs when coding the same with plain JS).

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/matias-lopez/pen/MWwGJYv)

```
    <ul class="main">
      <li
        class="main-item"
        style="background-color: blue;"
      ></li>
      <li
        class="main-item"
        style="background-color: green;"
      ></li>
      <li
        class="main-item"
        style="background-color: greenyellow;"
      ></li>
      <li
        class="main-item"
        style="background-color: yellow;"
      ></li>
    </ul>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
```

```
$(".main-item").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass("main-item-highlight");
    $(this)
      .siblings()
      .addClass("main-item-lowlight");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass("main-item-highlight");
    $(this)
      .siblings()
      .removeClass("main-item-lowlight");
    console.log($(this).siblings());
  }
);
```

However, when using jQuery 2, the yellow element stays at right as expected, please see **Codepen 2.4.2**.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/matias-lopez/pen/ZEGoLGa)

```
<script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

I have tested both in Chrome and Firefox, as in different computers, and the results don't change.

Any idea of what could cause that different behavior? If so, is there a way to achieve the same thing than in 2.4.2 with Vanilla JS or at least with jQuery 3?

I can also provide the plain JavaScript code if it can be of any help,

thanks in advance!